# Docker on Windows 10- D: drive not shared

Tags: docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

I have a Django rest project which I am dockerizing.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes: 
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

I first ran: `docker-compose build` which was successful. I then ran: `docker-compose up` which is giving me error as `ERROR: for web  Cannot create container for service web: D: drive is not shared. Please share it in Docker for Windows Settings`

How to fix this?

Comment: As it says, share it in the docker windows settings.  Have you looked at them?  https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c

Comment: Yes I understood that and did a quick google search but could not really figure out how to share it. Through some command or through docker console etc

Comment: https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c

Comment: Just found it! Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to activate a drive for sharing in the settings.

[Docker Desktop Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGwBZ.png)